# Keeping mobile browsers from arbitrarily wrapping text

Tags: mobile

I have a web page that uses em units to allow it to size automatically to any screen size, so the page displays fairly well on mobile devices. I notice, though,  that the iPad and iPhone (those are the only mobile devices I've checked so far) wrap blocks of text wherever they feel like it and this breaks the formatting if I've inserted spaces to line up lines.  For example, I might have the text

```
1.  This is the first sentence of some text 
    that wraps to a second line.
```

There's a Return at the end of "text." on the first line and then the next line has spaces at the beginning to get "that" to line up under "This." But now if an iPad decides to wrap this text after "some" the formatting is destroyed:

```
1.  This is the first line of some 
text          that wraps to a second line.
```

Is there a way to tell mobile browsers to not wrap the text themselves and just honor the Returns in the text?

Thanks

Comment: _“and this breaks the formatting if I've inserted spaces to line up lines”_ – don’t do that then. For spacing you should be using margin/padding, and not arbitrarily inserted space characters.

Comment: I don't have that much control over the markup.  This is a website builder and the text is entered through an RTE, similar to what is used here in Stackoverflow to enter questions.

Comment: Of course you can try and manipulate how that text is displayed and wrapped via the `white-space` property … but if you only allow it to wrap at the line breaks you set in your text for the desktop version, then that will most likely make the text overflow its container on mobile.

Comment: Yes. I think you are right. The text is overflowing its container on mobile devices and wrapping early. And thinking a bit more about it, I doubt now that the mobile browser is changing the container size.  It seems more likely that the text font didn't get scaled down exactly the right amount so it's slightly larger than what it should be and reaches the end of the container sooner. So my problem really is how to get text to scale down correctly when using em.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping your text in `<pre>` tags ?  it will respect your formatting.

Anyway, having the text reflow is preferable since it can rearrange and adapt to any screen size, there is nothing more annoying than having to scroll to the end of the lines to read the text.

If you want to have greater control of text output you will have to address each screen size individually, so I’d use the `media` element in CSS so you can apply different style depending on screen size.

google “screen size in css responsive” an you will see lots of resource about it.

Looking at your example text more closely, cold you enter `<li>` tags? so that the numbering could be placed outside? using list-style in CSS? I mean, if your problem is only with list numberings, maybe that can do it.

Best regards.